# How to keep turtle coordinates constant across screen sizes

Tags: python, troubleshooting, python3, python-gui

I have a program in Python that uses an image. The image is a little large, and because of that when it is opened by python, the entire image isn't visible on some computers (it fits vertically, but not horizontally).

The program opens a window the size of the image, and then places the image on the window. It then uses the point of the turtle window to find the output. When the image appears fully, the coordinates of the turtle are fine, and it works, but when it is chopped off, the coordinates don't work, and the output is wrong

Basically, I am wondering if there is a way to make sure that the coordinates stay the same even when used on computers with different screen sizes? (I used the turtle.setworldcoordinates() function, and it still gets messed up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly a solution, but I think it happened because the turtle window was larger than  the actual screen. The problem was solved when I made the screen smaller.